# Not understanding loops using each and map

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know there's native functions for each and map (i think) but we're being taught what goes on behind the scenes. So check this out..

```
var sampleInput = [ 
  [1, 3, 2], 
  [4, 23, 100],
  [7, 6, 3, -2]
];

function eachNew(coll, f) {
  if (Array.isArray(coll)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      f(coll[i], i);
    }
  } else {
    for (var key in coll) {
      f(coll[key], key);
    }
  }
}

function map(array, f) {
  var acc = [];
  eachNew(array, function(element, i) {
    acc.push(f(element, i));
  });
  return acc;
}
function max(array) {
    var largest = 0;
    eachNew(array, function(m){
        if (largest < m) { 
            largest = m};
    });
    return largest;
}
```

So I want to write a function `maximums`, that outputs an array with the max number in each array so `[3, 100, 7]`

I'm not sure how to write this. Here's my guess..

```
function maximum(array) {
    var array = [];{
    return map(array, max(array))
    };
    return array.push(max);
}
```

That doesn't look like a very good guess, but I've been trying!
Help please and thanks :)

Comment: hint: pay close attention to expected type of your function arguments. Also your browser console should be showing you errors that are big clues

Comment: Why did someone vote down this question?

Answer (score 3):

You're actually just about right there, just making it a little complicated. Remember, map takes a `function` as it's second argument, per your specifications. This function will be applied to the array passed as the first argument. So you just gotta use the two ingredients you have developed. Therefore, `maximum` becomes rather simple:

```
function maximum(array) {
    return map(array, max);
}

var numbers = maximum(sampleInput);

console.log(numbers);
```

It seems like you're doing this for school, so in the comments, I'd like you to tell us *why* the above works. And also, what was wrong with you trying to pass `max(array)` as the second argument to map. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Start by determining just what these functions do.

`eachNew`: Takes an object and a function. If the object is an array, calls the function passing each item and index in sequence. If the object is not an array, calls the function passing each value and key in sequence. (These are similar things, but not exactly the same.)

`map`: given an array and a function, builds a new array by using `eachNew` and calling the function `f` on each item and using what is returned to build the new array. `f` then is a transform for each item, and `map` transforms the whole array.

`max`: given an array, uses `eachNew` to determine and return the maximum element of the array.

Your goal is to write a function that transforms the elements of an array of arrays into an array of numbers, where each number is the maximum. You have a transform function (`map`), and a maximum function (`max`).

```
<transform>(<arrayOfArrays>, <functionThatTurnsAnArrayIntoAMaximum>) => <arrayOfMaximums>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this to your needs (i made no data-type checks, so you probably want to add that). I put comments in the code, so you can follow it. I did not want to give the full response, just another approach to your problem.

```
'use strict';

function map (array, f) {
  for (let element_index = 0; element_index < array.length; element_index++) {
    f(array[element_index]);
  }
}

function maximum (arrays) {
  let max_values = []; /* This will hold the max values */
  for (let array_index = 0; array_index < arrays.length; array_index++) {
    const array = arrays[array_index]; /* This is the current array of values */
    /*
    let's say for now, that the max value is the first element of the array.
    (assuming it holds numbers, and at least one of them)
    */
    let max_value_of_the_array = array[0];
    map(array, value => {
      /* This function will be applied on each value of the array.
         If the value is greater than the setted before, then change it.
         If this condition is never met, then the max value is already setted.
      */
      if (value > max_value_of_the_array) {
        max_value_of_the_array = value;
      }
    })
    /* Push the max value in the max values array */
    max_values.push(max_value_of_the_array);
  }
  /* After all arrays of the array has been iterated, and all max values getted,
  return the max_values array */
  return max_values;
}

const values = [
  [1, 5, 3],
  [11, 15, 13],
  [21, 25, 23]
]

console.log(maximum(values)); // [5, 15, 25]
```